# A "map" to only part of the elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

Is there a way, in Javascript (ES2015), to map only part of a array?

E.g.:

```
let m = someArray.map(function(n){ if(n===0) return n+1; }
```

That's it, it would return a mapped array that has less elements than the original one.

Is that something that we could accomplish out of the box with some functional programming technique?

Comment: How about a combination of `.filter()` and `.map()`?

Comment: `.reduce()` could do that, if JS allows an array as initial value. Only needs 1 cycle then.

Comment: `.filter` on `n === 0` then `.map`

Comment: @Pointy never heard of .filter(). Any example?

Comment: [Array.filer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) will take a callback, execute it on each elements, and keep only the ones for which the callback returned `true`

Comment: @Draconar it's easily google'able. Show some effort.

Answer (score 9):

Maps changing the number of elements are icky. It's better to filter first, then map:

```
let arr2 = arr.filter(e => e === 0).map(e => e + 1);
```

Comment: I've no idea why this was downvoted. I'd gladly improve the answer if nudged in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

This is easy with [array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions), which were introduced by the ECMAScript 6 draft, but will be postponed to ES7:

```
let m = [for (n of someArray) if (n===0) n+1]
```

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to skip unneeded elements with native [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19). But there's always [**Array.prototype.reduce()**](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.21) to save the day:

```
let m = someArray.reduce(function(mem, el) {
  if (el === 0) {
    mem.push(el + 1);
  }
  return mem;
}, []);
```

Comment: Slightly related: to break out of a `forEach`, there is `.some()`.

Comment: downvoted for using reduce in a way it's not meant to be used.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I probably don't get how exactly reduce is *meant* to be used. It's employed to create _something_ based on a collection. This something doesn't have to be a scalar, as Mozilla's [example of concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Flatten_an_array_of_arrays) shows.

Comment: `reduce` is meant to return a single `value` from an array of `value`. If `value` is an array, it's suppose to return a single `array` of an array of `array` which is ok in the exemple you linked to. Here you use `reduce` to `filter` and `map` an array, wich is not what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @raina77ow Mozilla's example of concatenation returns "a scalar" - the original structure was a table of tables, so a table is then returned.

Comment: You mean the result of `.reduce` should be of the same level as elements of collection? But don't you think it's an artificial limitation? One quite common use-case for `reduce` is `groupBy` function, when elements of some collection are placed into another collection, stacked together; is that also 'not how it meant to be used'?

Comment: @dievardump The linked spec explicitly states `Set accumulator to initialValue` ... `Return accumulator`. That's unambiguous and makes this answer entirely valid. If the answer didn't pass an `initialValue`, I might be able to see your point but as-is, it's fine

Answer (score 1):

[Array iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods) are (except for deprecated edge cases<sup>1</sup>) a concise way of expressing what you'd do with a loop (`for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { doSomething(arr[i]) }`). When the meaning of the method name is no longer representative, you acheive the exact opposite - instead of using a method that describe the operation, you're using one that doesn't and confuse the reader.

More so, *not* using this group of methods is [more performant](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/353). This mostly happens because invoking a function is "expensive".

To use the methods, while being concise, see [Bartek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32854948/3887516).

Alternatively, simply use a loop:

```
let m = [];
for(v of someArray) {
  if(v !== 0) {
    m.push(v + 1);
  }
}
```

<sup>1</sup> *When these methods are called, the length of the array is sampled, and any element added beyond this length from within the callback is not visited.*